# How do I manually rectify the actual shutter speed of old film camera

Tags: film, shutter-speed, shutter-actuations, konica

The camera in question is an old [Konica TC Autoreflex](http://www.buhla.de/Foto/Konica/eTCHaupt.html). Any shutter speed faster than 1/60 is off by about 2 stops, and gets progressively worse the faster the shutter speed (the fastest is 1/1000). I calculated appx shutter speed times using [this app](http://www.photoplug.de/) w/o the the phototransistor plug.

Does anyone here have any experience with adjusting physical shutter speeds? Do I need anything else other than a steady hand and a small screw driver? I will say that I've never opened up a camera before, but I really don't have anything to lose her except a couple of hours. The camera was gifted to me, and it came with a really beautiful f/1.4 prime lens in pristine condition.

Comment: I find this app HIGHLY dubious and  suspect. I would not trust an app on a phone to make a precision measurement of time based on sound it hears of one particular camera. Have you tested the app with a camera that is known to be accurate? individual cameras make different sounds, also when a camera takes a photo there are more then just the sound of the shutter, there is the mirror sound as well.   Take it to a camera repair shop and have it check by a pro.  Do you know if it is possible to adjust AND CALIBRATE the shutter speed and how to do it if you get into the camera?

Comment: You are right, and it took me a while to figure it out what each wave peak and trough means. I even went so far as to use the slow motion camera on my phone (limited to 120fps tho...). I crossed referenced it against my Nikon DSLR, and it checked out.

Comment: I did not read enough about the app, apparently it does not measure sound it measures light and converts it into electrical signals which i would think is better but Still, i am skeptical.

Comment: @Alaskaman If you read my post, it says that I did not use the phototransistor.

Comment: I would be interested to know how this app performs when tested along side more traditional testing equip.

Comment: me too, alaskaman. me too.

Comment: Since the camera has a light meter, manually adjusting the ISO to compensate for the shutter speed disparities might be a place to start...since it would not require opening up the camera.

Comment: @benrudgers sure, but it renders my camera practically useless if I can only shoot accurately at <1/30th...

Comment: The proper exposure can often be calculated manually using Sunny16 or externally using a light meter. The problem with the shutter is just requires an extra adjustment to the calculation. But any exposure can be used.

Comment: @Alaskaman I have been using the app with the provided hardware plug and even if it doesn't work with every smartphone or tablet (it probably depends on the actual hardware behind the microphone socket), when it works, it is actually quite accurate.

Answer (score 3):

The most common problem with slow mechanical shutters is that the lubricants have dried out. The speed of most mechanical shutters is controlled by changing the tension of a spring and if lubrication is insufficient, the shutter will simply move slower.

Such problems can be fixed by disassembling the camera, cleaning the mechanical parts of the shutter to remove the remains of the old lubricants, lubing it up and putting everything back together in the right order. It is not impossible to do, but you will likely need a service manual and a bit more knowledge and experience than just a steady hand and a screw driver.

Considering that the camera body is sold used with warranty from dealers starting at around 30€, I would recommend that you get yourself a cheap, but working new body if you are interested in using the lens.

Answer (score -1):

This camera has a mechanical shutter, adjusting it should be doable, if a little tricky. Just google for a service manual.

However, before you go that way do check your batteries. As I understand your camera uses two 1.3V PX675 batteries, which are illegal by now. If you put "normal" 1.5V batteries there it could be your light meter, not shutter, that was wrong